# can't set input value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following icon:

```
<i class="fa check-date fa-check-circle-o" data-abierta-date="1" data-date-price="250.00"></i>
```

and the following input:

```
<input type="text" id="convo-abierta" name="convo-abierta" value="">
```

I trying to set the value of an input using the following jquery:

```
$(".check-date").click(function(){
      $(".check-date").removeClass('fa-check-circle-o').addClass('fa-circle-thin');
      $(this).toggleClass('fa-circle-thin fa-check-circle-o');
      $("#convo-abierta").val($(this).data("abierta-date"));
    });
```

but the value of the input is always empty. I tried this code:

```
alert($(this).data("abierta-date"));
```

and get the value, but I don't understand why I can't set the value on my input field.

Comment: Yes, is unique I just checked

Comment: Provide sample online to replicate your issue

Comment: try to exec `$("#convo-abierta").val('foo');` in console, all is right?

Comment: I get this: $("#convo-abierta").val('foo');
[<input type=​"text" id=​"convo-abierta" name=​"convo-abierta" value>​]

Comment: @Jean Ya but is value of input changed or not?

Comment: Not, value still empty

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/mjcojy8w/

Comment: What returns `$('[id=convo-abierta]').length`??? So question is indeed, how do you check for duplicate IDs?

Comment: What is the output of $(this) within the click handler in the console?

Comment: @Jean some kind of magic, are you sure that there is only one elem with this id?

Comment: how about with this selector: val data = $("[data-abierta-date]").data("abierta-date"); ..... and $("#convo-abierta").val(data);

Comment: @A.Wolff it return 1

Comment: So unless you provide online sample as jsFiddle to replicate your issue, it is quite impossible to help you more, i'm stuck here. Maybe an event reset input value in some way. Just to be sure, is the click event fired?

Comment: @A.Wolff it's not explaining why does not working changing value from console

Comment: The above code works, something else must be clearing the input. Check your surrounding code.

Comment: @KirillPisarev ya absolutely

Comment: last attempt: exec in console and show us results: `$("#convo-abierta").attr('value', 'foo');`. May be the color of input and backgroung color are the same?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange behavior, cant explain why this happens, but if i understood right, this helped:

```
$("#convo-abierta").attr('value', $(this).data("abierta-date"));
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work in jsfiddle

Take a look. Is there something else going on in your code thats not represented in above?

http://jsfiddle.net/ws7oyznh/

```
       <i class="fa check-date fa-check-circle-o" data-abierta-date="1" data-date-price="250.00">Click ME 
        </i>
        <hr>
 <input type="text" id="convo-abierta" name="convo-abierta" value="">



$(".check-date").click(function () {
    $(".check-date").removeClass('fa-check-circle-o').addClass('fa-circle-thin');
    $(this).toggleClass('fa-circle-thin fa-check-circle-o');
    $("#convo-abierta").val($(this).data("abierta-date"));
});
```

Comment: this isn't an answer , it's nothing more than a  comment and should be in comment block. Answers are meant for you to ask questions in